# Django: updating database row via table cell

Tags: django

Trying to create a Display in Django, which would look like this.

link: http://i47.tinypic.com/2lk2mw2.png

1. the number of fruits everyday is dynamic and different everyday.
2. the comment field is to be editable by the admin. the input would 
   then be used to update the row in the database

problem: so far I'm uncertain about how to go about allowing users to edit the comment column and present the changes in the database

**

- fruits.html

**

```
{% for item in nodes %}
<tr>
    <td class = "tablebord"><a href ="/nodes/node/{{ item.nodeid }}/">{{ 
     item.nodeid }}</a></td>
    <td class = "tablebord">{{ item.lastseen }} </td>
    <td class = "tablebord"><div contenteditable>{{ item.comment }}    <p>
            <form action="" method="get">
              <input type="text" name="q">
              <input type="submit" value="test">
            </form>
     </p> </div> </td>
    <td class = "tablebord">{{ item.lastipaddr }} </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: So what is the question? You are getting errors? Please ask something specific.

Comment: I'm unable to edit the comment columns and update the database accordingly

Answer (score 2):

One solution that occurs to me:

**In HTML:**

Change method in form to POST.

Add CSRF Token to form.

Add hidden input with nodeid for parsing in view.

Pre-fill input with current comment.

```
<!-- Comment Cell -->
<td class = "tablebord">
  <div contenteditable>
    <form action="" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="text" name="comment" value={{ item.comment }} />
      <input type="hidden" value={{ item.nodeid }} name="nodeid" />
      <input type="submit" value="edit" />
    </form>
  </div>
</td>
```

**In views.py:**

Import decorator for CSRF Token and Node model

Decorate view with CSRF Protect.

Check if form is submitted.

If so, get node and change comment.

Render template.

```
# decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect

from app.Node.models import Node

# view to handle table
@csrf_protect
def fruits(request):
  nodes = Nodes.objects.all()
  # user is posting: get edited node, change comment, and save
  if request.POST:
    nodeid = request.POST.get('nodeid')
    edited_node = nodes.get(nodeid=nodeid)
    edited_node.comment = request.POST.get('comment')
    edited_node.save()

  # render template with nodes
  return render(request, 'fruits.html', {'nodes':nodes})
```

Hope this answers your problem.

Comment: works good solution however, I am stuck with a csrf error, followed your steps however it doesnt go away. reading the documentation on middleware now

Comment: make sure `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` is in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in `settings.py`, `{% csrf_token %}` is inside `<table></table>`, make sure `from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect` is in views.py, and `@csrf_protect` is above the view function.  That's all I can think of.

Comment: overcame the csrf problem by utilizing the @csrf_exempt tag