# How to update a form and update table cell in Django

Tags: html, django, django-forms

I am very new Django and python, trying to learn and build a webapp.

I want to show some data to user in a table format. The user should be able to add, delete and update records in the table view.

I am able to achieve the add, delete part but, cannot get my head around updating the existing records.

Ideally, i want the row data to be populated in a modal view as a django form when clicked on "edit" button of a particular row. But unable to even get the basic update from a editable table row. Here is my sample code..

I tried this at below link but, did not help .. or may be i did not understand. 
[Django: updating database row via table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411183/django-updating-database-row-via-table-cell)

**models.py**

```
# Create your models here.

class customerDataModel(models.Model):
    customerName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    custormerLocation = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    custormerAge = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    custormerLanguage = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.customerName
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from . models import customerDataModel


class addCustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = customerDataModel
        fields = ('customerName', 'custormerLocation', 'custormerAge', 'custormerLanguage')

        widgets = {
            'customerName': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                    }
                ),
            'custormerLocation': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                    }
                ),
            'custormerAge': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                    }
                ),

            'custormerLanguage': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                    }
                ),


            }
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . forms import addCustomerForm
from . models import customerDataModel
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your views here.

#from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = addCustomerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # print("VALID")
            form.save()

    customer_table_data = customerDataModel.objects.all()
    form = addCustomerForm
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'customer_table_data' : customer_table_data ,'form' : form})
    #return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")


def delete_customer_row(request, id):
    customerDataModel.objects.filter(id=id).delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))


def edit_customer_row(request, id):

    print('The value in ID is ', id)

    instance = customerDataModel.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = addCustomerForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
             print("VALID")
             form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

**template.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Customer Information</h2>

<form method="POST">

    {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form }}

     <br>
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>



<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Customer Name</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Laungage</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>



    {% for rowitem in customer_table_data %}

    <tr>
        <form action="{% url 'edit_customer_row' rowitem.id %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
        <td>{{rowitem.customerName}}</td>
        <td><div contenteditable>{{rowitem.custormerLocation}}</div></td>
        <td>{{rowitem.custormerAge}}</td>
        <td>{{rowitem.custormerLanguage}}</td>
        <!-- <td><a href="{% url 'edit_customer_row' rowitem.id %}" <button>edit</button></a></td> -->
        <td><input type="submit" value="edit"/></td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'delete_customer_row' rowitem.id %}" <button>delete</button></a></td>
        </form>
    </tr>

    {% endfor %}


  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with that approach, is what are you going to do when the data your user enters fails validation on the server? If you redirect back to the table view, how will it be able to tell the user why it is ignoring what he asked for?

My approach in a somewhat similar situation, was an initially hidden Django Form at the bottom (or top if you prefer) of the table. Use some Javascript to populate the form's fields from the modal pop-up, and to POST it. At the server end, everything proceeds in the usual way. If validation fails the table view comes back with errors in the form, and Javascript (in Jquery onReady context) can immediately un-hide the form and make sure that the error messages get displayed attached to the previously entered data. The user can edit his response in the form, or could click again on a table row to start from scratch (the modal will overwrite the old data displayed in the form).

The work involved is at the client JQuery end. I don't think there's anything out of of the ordinary at the Django end.

The easier approach is a second round-trip to the server. In the table, have a clickable  "Update" icon on each row, which is a link to a conventional FormView such as "/foo/44/update" (`{{url "foo:foo_update" pk=object.pk}}` or similar in the template), 44 being the `object.pk` of the object that was represented in that row.